# How to group by and sum based on values in another column

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe for example:

```
Date           Amount.       Type 
1/2/2011.   200.             S
 1/2/2011.    300.             R
 1/3/2012.     400.           S
  1/3/2012.    300.           S
```

I need :

```
Date.         Result.     Flow
1/2/2011    S-R.       -100
 1/3/2011.   S+S.       700
```

Now wherever R occurs, I need to subtract the amount from that date and wherever S ovcjes, I need to add.

I tried: df.groupby([df.Date.values, df.Type])[“Amount”])

But this didn’t give me what I want.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all R to negative values:

```
df['amount'] = [x[1]['amount'] if x[1]['type'] == 'S' else x[1]['amount'] * -1 for x in df.iterrows()]
```

Group by 'date':

```
df2 = df.groupby(df['date']).sum()
```

Result:

```
            amount
date              
2011-01-02    -100
2011-01-03     700
```

If you want to add columns or change names you can do so from there.